# Merge data for same id

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
ItemCode    AttributeCode        AttributeValue
----------- -------------------- ----------------
ITEM-000001 BUTTONS              2B
ITEM-000001 COLOR                NAVY
ITEM-000001 FABRIC               A-W
ITEM-000001 LAPEL                NOTCH
ITEM-000001 PATTERN              STRIPE
ITEM-000001 SEASON               A6
ITEM-000001 SUITSTYLE            SB
ITEM-000001 VENT                 NONE
```

How i can show above data in single row as those are having same ItemCode?

Kind regards,
Om

Comment: please format your question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ItemCode, 
   (SELECT AttributeValue FROM Table x WHERE x.ItemCode = t.ItemCode AND x.AttributeCode = 'BUTTONS') as [Buttons],
   (SELECT AttributeValue FROM Table x WHERE x.ItemCode = t.ItemCode AND x.AttributeCode = 'COLOR') as [Color],
   ..... repeat for all .....
FROM Table t
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

Comment: Thank you.
Is there is other way to manage those dynamically, if in future the columns data 'AttributeCode' will having more data?

Comment: Only by generating your code dynamically.  You can also look into `PIVOT`, however that has to have all of the items hard coded as well.

Comment: I think that we can create dynamic select query by using column data through Cursor or there is any other way we can create dynamic query?

Comment: It could be done completely in SQL using a cursor, however I would try and build the SQL in an external language if possible.